# Joining two working sql queries gets wrong results - Where am i going wrong

Tags: mysql, join

I have two queries that individually return the correct data, but when I tried to join them the returned data is wrong. 
Query one is:

```
SELECT op.orders_id, op.products_id, op.products_name, op.final_price, op.products_quantity
FROM orders_products op
WHERE op.orders_id = 21535
```

Query two is:

```
SELECT opa.products_options_values_id, opa.products_prid
FROM orders_products_attributes opa
WHERE opa.orders_id = 21535
```

The combined query I tried was:

```
SELECT op.orders_id, op.products_id, op.products_model, op. products_name, op.final_price, op.products_quantity, opa.products_options_values_id, opa.products_prid
FROM orders_products op
JOIN orders_products_attributes opa
ON op.orders_id = opa.orders_id
WHERE op.orders_id = 21535
```

Fiddle is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ef9be/5

I've no idea how to fix this. I tried Group BY on opa.products_options_values_id but that caused issues because two results of 40 are in the data result.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `join` condition, you used `orders_id`. You should use `orders_products_id` like this:

```
SELECT op.orders_id, op.products_id, op.products_model, op. products_name,
       op.final_price, op.products_quantity, opa.products_options_values_id,
       opa.products_prid
FROM orders_products op
JOIN orders_products_attributes opa ON op.orders_products_id = opa.orders_products_id
WHERE op.orders_id = 21535
```

Comment: Excellent. That fixed it. I'm a bit new to JOINS. I was surprised I even got it to give me anything at all. Every day I learn something new on here