# Problems with joined query depending on what customer orders

Tags: sql, join

I had to make some edits to an sql query because I needed to include some additional data and at first I thought it was all sorted until today when someone placed an order and the new query returned only one product, and not the 5 ordered. This is due to some products not having attributes.

The new query is as follows:

```
SELECT op.orders_id, op.products_id, op.products_model, op. products_name,
   op.final_price, op.products_quantity, opa.products_options_values_id,
   opa.products_prid
   FROM orders_products op
   JOIN orders_products_attributes opa ON op.orders_products_id = opa.orders_products_id
   WHERE op.orders_id = 21679
```

I have set up an sql fiddle with the relevant database information here; http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/105ec

The original query does return 5 reults as expected and is:

```
   SELECT op.orders_id, op.products_id, op.products_model, op. products_name,
   op.final_price, op.products_quantity
   FROM orders_products op
   WHERE op.orders_id = 21679
```

The original question complete with sqlfiddle to show the data that is required for that particular order can be found here; [Joining two working sql queries gets wrong results - Where am i going wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737545/joining-two-working-sql-queries-gets-wrong-results-where-am-i-going-wrong)

Any changes to this query must still return the correct results for order 21535 used in the previous fiddle.

It looks like it's due to the JOIN used which is referencing orders_products_id, but the product will not be in the one table if no attributes are required.

I can't use orders_id for the join as that gives me wrong results as per previous question.

Any suggestions on this as I'm completely stuck now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a `left join` because not all products seem to have attributes:

```
SELECT op.orders_id, op.products_id, op.products_model, op. products_name,
op.final_price, op.products_quantity, opa.products_options_values_id,
opa.products_prid
FROM orders_products op
LEFT JOIN orders_products_attributes opa ON op.orders_products_id = opa.orders_products_id
WHERE op.orders_id = 21679
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Can you explain why LEFT JOIN gives a different result to JOIN. Always willing to learn how and why.

Comment: Because your original query filtered out products that have no attributes.  A `left join` keeps them.